# Where should I put my AsyncTask class for my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have been trying to make a feature in my app where I can login and then fetch data from my database through the Django REST Framework. My logging in works as it only uses POST, but retrieving items does not work.

For some reason my AsyncTask does not get called for retrieving posts.

I have placed my AsyncTask for both activities, which are `login` and `posts`, on a separate java file only for handling Web Server stuff.

I am wondering if this is because I should put AsyncTask on each activities.

login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button LoginButton;
    EditText uUserName, uPassWord;
    WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests AuthHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //SetupHomeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SetupHomeBtn);

        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);

        uUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginUserBox);
        uPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginPassBox);

        //AuthHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendDeviceDetails();

        // Moves user to the main page after validation
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // gets the username and password from the EditText
                String strUserName = uUserName.getText().toString();
                String strPassWord = uPassWord.getText().toString();

                // API url duh
                String APIUrl = "http://192.168.0.18:8000/token-auth/";

                // If the user is authenticated, then transfer to the MainActivity page
                if (APIAuthentication(strUserName, strPassWord, APIUrl)){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Posts.class));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean APIAuthentication(String un, String pw, String url){
        // when it wasn't static -> AuthHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendAPIRequests();
        AuthHelper = new WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests();

        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // Attempt to input info to the Django API
            postData.put("username", un);
            postData.put("password", pw);

            // Putting the data to be posted in the Django API
            AuthHelper.execute(url, postData.toString());

            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

posts.java

```
public class Posts extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView postsSect;
    Button postsDoneBtn;
    WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests PostsHelper;
    StringBuilder postsBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();
        postDetailsHelper.ListPosts();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

        PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();

        postsDoneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PostsDoneButton);

        postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("192.168.0.18:8000/api");
        postDetailsHelper.ListPosts();
        postDetailsHelper.postDetailsCalled('n');

        postsDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Posts.this, MainActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    public class PostsDetails {
        //String post_title, post_content;
        ArrayList<Integer> post_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> post_title = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> post_content = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean isPDCalled;

        // sets if Post details are called
        boolean postDetailsCalled(char called) {
            if (called == 'y'){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // checks if postsDetails functions are called for AsyncTask
        boolean getIsPDCalled(){
            return isPDCalled;
        }

        // calls the execute for AsyncTask
        private void callPostDetails(String theurl){
            PostsHelper = new WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests();
            // sets if post details are called
            postDetailsCalled('y');
            // executes AsyncTask
            PostsHelper.execute(theurl);
        }

        // sets values for the posts arrays
        public void setPost(int p_id, String p_title, String p_content) {
            post_id.add(p_id);
            post_title.add(p_title);
            post_content.add(p_content);
        }

        // Lists the posts from the database
        public void ListPosts() {
            /////////// add functionality if a post was deleted and was clicked
            postsSect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostsSection);
            postsSect.setText(post_title.get(post_title.size()) + "\n");
            for (int i = post_id.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                postsSect.append(post_title.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WSAdapter.java

```
// I forgot what WS stands for, but this class serves as an adapter for JSON and Online stuff
// I think it stands for With-Server Adapter
public class WSAdapter extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    static public class SendAPIRequests extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Add a pre-execute thing

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.e("TAG", params[0]);
            Log.e("TAG", params[1]);
            String data = "";

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {

                // Sets up connection to the URL (params[0] from .execute in "login")
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();

                // Sets the request method for the URL
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // Tells the URL that I am sending a POST request body
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                // To write primitive Java data types to an output stream in a portable way
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                // Writes out a byte to the underlying output stream of the data posted from .execute function
                wr.writeBytes("postData=" + params[1]);
                // Flushes the postData to the output stream
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                // Representing the input stream
                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                // Preparing input stream bytes to be decoded to charset
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                StringBuilder dataBuffer = new StringBuilder();

                // Translates input stream bytes to charset
                int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                    char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                    inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                    // concatenates data characters from input stream
                    dataBuffer.append(current);
                }
                data = dataBuffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // Disconnects socket after using
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

            Log.e("TAG", data);
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // expecting a response code fro my server upon receiving the POST data
            Log.e("TAG", result);

            Posts.PostsDetails postsHelper = new Posts().new PostsDetails();

            // For posts
            try {
                if (postsHelper.getIsPDCalled()){
                    JSONObject pJObj = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray pJObjArray = pJObj.getJSONArray("posts");

                    for (int i = 0; i < pJObjArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pJObj_data = pJObjArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        postsHelper.setPost(pJObj_data.getInt("id"), "post_title", "post_content");
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Toast.makeText(JSonActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Json","Exception = "+e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can and should put the network calls functions in a separate java file for better readability and test-coverage.

Apart from that, i would suggest to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) as your HTTP client. It helps you to manage all the dirty things like headers and converters etc, so you can put all your effort on your logic and implementing your callback actions.